# Listening to dynamically created shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny

I want to dynamically create modules in my main app. The modules should also contain a `delete` button upon which I want to delete the very module in my app.

The following code achieves that but only if I add a dependency on `handlers` itself, which means the observer is also fires whenever I *add* a new module.

Conceptually, I would like to use `isolate(handlers())` because I do not want to take a dependency on `handlers` itself but only on the reactives inside `handlers`.

So why does  `isolate(handlers())` not work? How do I take dependency properly on reactives from my module?

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)

example_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(id = id,
           h3(id),
           actionButton(ns("delete"), "Delete Me!")
  )
}

example_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  killMe <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$delete, killMe(TRUE))

  list(delete = killMe)
}

ui <- fluidPage(actionButton("add", "Add"), div(id = "container"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  handlers <- reactiveVal(list())
  n <- 1

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    id <- paste0("ex_", n)
    n <<- n + 1
    insertUI("#container", "beforeEnd", example_ui(id))
    new_handler <- setNames(list(callModule(example_server, id)),
                            id)
    handlers(c(handlers(), new_handler))
  })

  observe({
    ## would not work: isolate(handlers())
    hdls <- handlers() 
    deregister <- lapply(names(hdls), function(id) {
      handle <- hdls[[id]]
      if (!is.null(handle) && handle$delete()) {
        removeUI(paste0("#", id))
        id
      } else {
        NULL
      }
    }) %>% purrr::flatten_chr()
    hdls[deregister] <- NULL
    handlers(hdls)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess the proper way of doing it would be to create `observers` on the change on `handlers` like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  handlers  <- reactiveVal(list())
  observers <- list()

  n <- 1

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    id <- paste0("ex_", n)
    n <<- n + 1
    insertUI("#container", "beforeEnd", example_ui(id))
    new_handler <- setNames(list(callModule(example_server, id)),
                            id)
    handlers(c(handlers(), new_handler))
  })

  observe({
    hds <- handlers()
    req(length(hds) > 0)
    new <- setdiff(names(hds),
                   names(observers))

    obs <- setNames(lapply(new, function(n) {
      observeEvent(hds[[n]]$delete(), {
        removeUI(paste0("#", n))
        hds <- handlers()
        hds[n] <- NULL
        handlers(hds)
        observers[n] <<- NULL
      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    }), new)
    observers <<- c(observers, obs)
  })
}
```